# 504 gateway timeout error NodeJs

Tags: node.js, http, http-status-code-504, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an application which is hosted in DC/OS instance, The application query the snowflake database and get the result. I am using [snowflake sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snowflake-sdk) to to query the snowflake data base, we are also streaming the result we are getting from snowflake.

```
 var statement = connection.execute({
          sqlText: sql,
          complete: function (err, stmt, rows) {
    var stream = stmt.streamRows();
                  callback(err, stream, response);
}}
```

But if querying is large and the processing of query takes time in snowflake , I get 504 gateway timeout error at my client.although the node service is still running , but suppose I am hitting DC/OS from browser/postman I will get 504 timeout error here but snowflake returns result to my node service.  What is the right strategy to avoid it ?
this is the error which I am getting at my client from the server though my node service still maintains connection with snowflake and get the result from snowflake.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @raccoon we started processing the query in background, we process the request and store the result in Cassandra and later get it.

Comment: okay, got it. Thanks @user3649361 for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check what your statement timeout is set to?

Can you try out the following :

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html

```
# set timeout to 15 minutes
alter user USERNAME set STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 900;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-session.html

STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS =

Examples
Set the lock timeout for statements executed in the session to 1 hour (3600 seconds):

```
alter session set STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 3600;
```

Set the lock timeout for statements executed in the session back to the default:

```
alter session unset STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS;
```

Have you reached out to snowflake support?